# convolution chi function with itself

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Find $f*f$ where $f= \chi _{[0,1]}$

Find its convolution

---

$$ \chi_{[0,1] } = \begin{Bmatrix}
1 & x \in [0,1]  
\\  0 & x \not \in [0,1]
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
**Convolution Def**

$$ f*g= \int f(\tau) g(t-\tau) d\tau$$

Sketch $f(-\tau)$

[image]

Sketch $f(\tau)$

[image]

Sketch $f(t-\tau)$

[image]

and let us consider $t\in [0,1]$

[image]

I know it makes a rectangle so the area is length times width which is $t*1=1$ but not sure how to interpret the integral

$$ \int^1_0 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)= \int \text{??} d\tau = \int^t_0 1 d \tau =t $$

I am missing stuff for $t[1,2]$. also when its zero for the values at $t>2$ and $t<0$
_______________________-

This is an example 20.1.2 on Gaskett Fourier

the answer is

$$f*g(x) = \begin{Bmatrix}
  0 & \text{ if  } x\leq 0
\\x & \text{ if  } 0\leq x\leq 1
\\2-x & \text{ if  } 1\leq x\leq 2
\\ 0 & \text{ if  } x\geq 0
 \end{Bmatrix} $$

Also do not understand why

$$\int_R f(x-t) g(t) = \int 1_0 \chi _{[0,1]} (x-) dt = meausure ([0,1 ] \cap [x-1,x]) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Don't think too hard.

**Hint 2**: Just write down the integral and compute.

**Hint 3**: Remember that $\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_S(x) f(x)\ dx = \int_S f(x)\ dx$.

Answer (score 1):

For $t \le 1,$

$$ \int^t_0 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)= \int^t_0 1\times 1 d\tau = \int^t_0 1 d \tau =t$$

For $t>1$,

$$ \int^t_0 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)= \int^1_0 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)           +             \int^t_1 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)= $$

$$1+\int^t_1 f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d(\tau)=1+\int^t_1 f(t-\tau)\times (0) d(\tau)= 1$$